# Modular Multiplicative Inverse function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, inverse, modulo

I have problem for calculate modular multiplicative inverse.
example I have integer `A = 151` and `M = 541`. 151 mod 541. inverse mod 151 to 541 is 43
how to calculate modular multiplicative inverse in matlab ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using [**`gcd`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcd.html) and [**`mod`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) functions as follows:

```
A = 151;   M = 541;

[G, C, ~] = gcd(A,M);
if G==1  % The inverse of a(mod b) exists only if gcd(a,b)=1
    ModMultInv = mod(C,M)
else disp('Modular multiplicative inverse does not exist for these values')
end
```

**Output:-**

```
ModMultInv =
    43
```